# I'm trying to change the value of button when the data is submitted, but it's not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
 $('#submitAtt').click(function(event){

  event.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({

  url: "submitattendance.php",
  method: "post",
  data: $('form').serialize(),
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(strmessage){
    $('#message').text("Submitted Successfully");
    alert('clicked');
   $("#submitAtt").text('Save');
  }
})
    })
```

I'm trying to change the value of button when the data is submitted, but its not working ..

Comment: What do you mean by not working, can you elaborate? Is there any error in browser's console?

Comment: yes, i want to change the text of button when i submit the data to updated..,you see this line  $("#submitAtt").text('Save');?? i dont know what's problem there.., but when i put that outside of the function it's working..

Comment: So it could be the problem with PHP file, your Ajax fail and it doesn't execute the success function. Check your PHP log to see what is the problem.

Comment: but there's nothing wrong with my code??

Comment: @AkopoIto01 see browser developer mode **Network**. Make sure you Ajax is post back `success` status **200**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of button it is. If it's a button like such 
`<button>some_text</button>`
Then you can use
`$(#id).html('some_text');`. However, if it's a `<input type='button' value='some_text'/>` then you should use `$(#id).prop('value', 'some_text')`. Keep in kind if your PHP file is throwing an error than the success script will not run. To check if it's a problem with the PHP simply write `console.log('test')` within the success function and if 'test' does not show up in your console then the PHP script isn't working.

Comment: oh my .. Got it .. thank you for the help ...what if i want to change the background color?? .. should i change value to background?

Comment: No. Since background is not a valid property. $().prop() only works for element properties like value, class, placeholder, etc. To change the background color you would have to use $('#id').css('background-color', 'some_color'); you can check out jQuery's full documentation here https://api.jquery.com/